# How to use gentelella alela select2 option in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, gentelella

I found they have select2 file in their  vendor folder, so i linked them (those links works when i open these two files in web browser).
in header

```
 <link href="{{asset('adminbackend/vendors/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

in Footer

```
<script src="{{asset('adminbackend/vendors/select2/dist/js/select2.full.js')}}"></script>
```

in body

```
 <div class="item form-group">
                        <select class="form-control select2-multi" name="tags[]">
                            @foreach($tags as $tag)
                            <option value="{{$tag->id}}"> {{$tag->name}} </option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

in body

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(.select2-multi').select2();
</script>
```

but, still it not working.. this code found in here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNUYaLWdR04&list=PLwAKR305CRO-Q90J---jXVzbOd4CDRbVx&index=43

Comment: you should assign it inside jquery document ready function

Answer (score 1):

It could be the missing quote in the script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.select2-multi').select2(); 
});
```

Could you try this?